# Reading MNIST database in C++. All pixel values are zero

Tags: c++

I'm attempting to read the testing images file and have success in reading the header parameters(magic number, number of images, number of rows, etc) specified but keep reading zeros for the individual pixel values. I created an if condition where the program would print out some ofthe non-zero pixel values and then return from the function. I am working on a little-endian computer, thus I have to reverse the inputs. Does anyone know why all the pixel inputs would be zero?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

void loadDatabase(int NumberOfImages, int DataOfAnImage,std::vector<std::vector<double> >&arr);

int main()
{
    printf("Starting load database......\n");

    std::vector<std::vector<double> > images;
    loadDatabase(60000,784,images);

    printf("We succesfully have loaded the database\n");
return 0;

}
 using namespace std;

// The format of the inout MNIST Database is specefied within their website.
// We are required to flip the the incoming order and then place the images into a 1-D array.
// Reversing input function
int ReverseInt (int i)
{
    unsigned char ch1, ch2, ch3, ch4; // The 32 bit 
    ch1=i&255;
    ch2=(i>>8)&255;
    ch3=(i>>16)&255;
    ch4=(i>>24)&255;
    return((int)ch1<<24)+((int)ch2<<16)+((int)ch3<<8)+ch4;
}

void loadDatabase(int NumberOfImages, int DataOfAnImage,std::vector<std::vector<double> >&arr)
{
    //Creating the appropriatly sized array in C++
    arr.resize(NumberOfImages,vector<double>(DataOfAnImage));
    // Creating the buffer named "file" from the location on the computer
    std::ifstream file ("/Users/images",ios::binary);
    //file.is_open checks to see whether our stream is open and if so we cotinue
    if (file.is_open())
    {
        // Magic number is defined in the MNIST database. The magic number is an integer where the first 2 bytes are zero
        // and the 3rd byte represents the type of code, and the 4th byte determines the dimensions of the matrix/vector;
        int magic_number=0;
        //Number of images is images in the whole testing labels/images file
        int number_of_images=0;
        //Cols and rows
        int n_rows=0;
        int n_cols=0;
        //We read the first integer from the file
        file.read ((char*)&magic_number,sizeof(magic_number)); 
    printf("magic number = %d\n", magic_number);
    //Flip the magic number since the MNIST database is organized as per Big-Endian
        magic_number= ReverseInt(magic_number); 
    printf("reversed magic number = %d\n", magic_number);
     //Read the next integer that represents the number of images
        file.read((char*)&number_of_images,sizeof(number_of_images));
    printf("number of images = %d\n", number_of_images);
        //Again reverse (big-endian -> little-endian)
        number_of_images= ReverseInt(number_of_images); 
    printf("reversed number of images = %d\n", number_of_images);
     //Read rows
        file.read((char*)&n_rows,sizeof(n_rows));
        n_rows= ReverseInt(n_rows);
        //Read cols
        file.read((char*)&n_cols,sizeof(n_cols));
        n_cols= ReverseInt(n_cols);
        // From here forward we access the individual images that are stored in consecutive locations each 32 bits. 
        // The image pixels are placed in a 1-D array.       
    int flag =0;
        for(int i=0;i<number_of_images;++i)
        {
            for(int r=0;r<n_rows;++r)
            {
                for(int c=0;c<n_cols;++c)
                {
                    // The MNIST database only stores in black and white and thus we need only read 1 byte of information per pixel.
                    // The images themselves are arranged in little-endian
                    unsigned char temp = 1; 
                    file.read((char*)&temp,sizeof(temp));
            temp = ReverseInt(temp);
            if(temp !=0)
            {   flag++;
                printf("temp[%d][(%d*%d)+%d] = %d = %x\n", i, n_rows, r, c, temp, temp); 
                if(flag >9)
                    return;
            }
                    arr[i][(n_rows*r)+c]= (double)temp;
           // printf("temp = %d = %x\n", temp, temp); 
           // printf("arr[%d][(%d*%d)+%d]=%x\n", i, n_rows, r, c, arr[i][(n_rows*r)+c]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
return;
}
```

The output is as follows:

[There are no "temp" non-zero values printed as can be seen in the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2porG.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon.  Do not post links to images when the output is simple text.  Copy'n'paste the text into the question, and indent it like you do code.

Comment: `temp = ReverseInt(temp);` Drop this - it makes no sense to reverse a value that's only one byte large. You take an `unsigned char`, with values in the range [0, 255]. You convert it to integer, in the same range - so low-order byte is [0-255], the rest are zeros. You reverse that integer - now high-order byte is [0-255] and the rest are zero. Finally, you convert that integer back to `unsigned char`, which takes the low-order byte - which is always zero.

Comment: Deleting that bit of code did indeed work and it does indeed make sense. Thank you. I will also read the About and How to Ask pages moving forward.